# Play Button not working in UNITY (Camera not starting)[Error : Bake paused in play mode]

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I have created a new project (entirely new) , then I pressed the play option.Nothing is happening .
**Just a error message : Bake paused in play mode.**

[After pressing the play button (Nothing is happening)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsbfE.png)

This thing started happening after I was working something on some project in morning. Even i updated the unity version .Right now I am on UNITY 2018 one
I have already checked my web cam and it's  working .
Please if any know how to make it working again , please help .

Comment: `Bake paused in play mode` should not be the problem. You can disable the baking in the lightning settings: `Window -> Lightning -> Settings` Uncheck `Auto Generate` under `Realtime Lightning` - it is difficult to help you remote. Seems like Unity is doing some processes in background. Remove all Unity Versions, restart and reinstall?

Comment: Thanks dome12b , i have reinstalled it , it's working man . 
Thank you bro